# How to configure Qt Creator to work for a normal c++ project?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm new to using Qt Creator. All I wanted to do is write a plain c++ code and use GNU build utilities to build and run as I wont be using Qt library at all. Please help.

Comment: You could avoid using QtCreator. You can even build Qt applications without using QtCreator (and without even using Qmake, just pkg-config and moc, and usual tools).

Comment: If it's pure C++ and you're never going to use the Qt libraries, there are other (arguably more suitable) IDEs.

Comment: +1 to this question. I am in the same dilemma. There seems to be no good debugging frontends on Windows apart from MSVC. QtCreator with Qt - the offline installer is 1.2GB - jeez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off Qt in your `pro` file: just write `QT =`  (nothing) there. You can remove `qmake` stage from your project build settings and write your own `Makefile`.

Also, I see no reason to use `qtcreator` then.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at this just the other day.

You can write `CONFIG -= qt` in the .pro file.  Also, if you need, you can set up the precise build steps (e.g. running `make`) in the project settings.

The new version 2.4 (still beta) has an option to create a "plain C++" project.  This also uses the `CONFIG -= qt` setting.